# git hour 'hours is not a git command

Tags: git

So, I am trying to get the hours of work from a git repo I am working on using this tool

https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/git-hours

I setup vagrant, follow the instructions on the site, install my repo, then try to run the command.

I get:

```
git: 'hours' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
```

What am I doing wrong? This tool looks powerful, but I think I am making a basic error.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the github repo for that feature it says "Build Failing" at the top. So something is obviously wrong. I would try to contact the developer or wait a few days and try it again.

Edit:
There is an issue up about this in the repo here, https://github.com/kimmobrunfeldt/git-hours/issues/6

The author suggests trying out the command

```
git-hours
```

with the dash.

Comment: Yep, I saw that, did that. I thought I might be making some basic mistake though. I probably still am!

Comment: Please see the latest comments in the GitHub issue #6.